# Finding the correspondence of the elements of two columns in a two dimensional array in another 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a file of data contains `X` and `Y` positions and some other properties in the extra columns. This file has been used with a code and some calculation has been done on the extra columns. On the other hand the order of original file based on `X` and `Y` has been changed. Each file contains almost 25000 rows. I would like to find the fastest way to give order to the second file based on `X` and `Y` positions in the first file and append extra properties to the original file.
an example of the first file:

```
149.021 204.492 0.187235 0.233713 0.457313 1
478.467 421.622 -0.10692 -0.141686 0.80883 1
160.736 220.413 -0.0236415 -0.0962102 0.591765 1
485.327 60.0308 -0.121497 -0.195995 0.205639 1
497.014 59.1949 -0.00143256 0.0205032 0.179389 1
468.399 421.935 0.0709232 0.144875 1.15085 1
492.597 53.4478 -0.0407651 0.0535784 0.826217 1
153.751 1.22557 -0.194406 0.107156 1.15702 1
66.8625 38.0019 -0.178805 0.1475 0.732446 1
410.695 366.188 -0.179227 -0.216467 0.414247 1
502.513 361.575 -0.114651 -0.0094424 0.966985 1
398.835 61.0347 -0.160149 -0.216436 0.761429 1
459.336 177.548 0.174666 -0.0481024 1.43403 1
111.007 236.622 0.23444 0.201739 1.15933 1
46.9406 255.214 -0.00335369 -0.0306168 0.494205 1
236.685 335.616 -0.00456215 0.0871247 1.26644 1
329.606 231.826 0.131988 0.00122767 1.1712 1
335.467 128.234 -0.0490298 -0.0520559 0.61536 1
53.6696 191.586 0.194366 0.18284 1.47372 1
359.599 148.55 0.127806 -0.0621203 0.559922 1
494.895 431.539 0.201591 0.206185 0.818496 1
342.083 439.732 -0.00373251 -0.0841907 0.383131 1
426.053 201.598 0.0908615 -0.130614 1.23092 1
499.756 443.071 0.195117 0.0999967 0.312757 1
363.483 369.165 0.0791957 -0.0225179 0.319282 1
```

Part of the second file:

```
494.895 431.539 -0.0175584 -0.109455 12 1
53.6696 191.586 -0.062199 0.504269 15 1
46.9406 255.214 0.405452 0.237562 6 1
329.606 231.826 -0.371944 -0.0784321 19 1
342.083 439.732 0.100881 -0.0167807 11 1
111.007 236.622 0.0578686 0.223055 12 1
363.483 369.165 0.518668 -0.0620763 18 1
485.327 60.0308 0.271933 -0.0514785 6 1
66.8625 38.0019 -0.191781 -0.104952 9 1
468.399 421.935 -0.1768 0.0328495 8 1
499.756 443.071 0.0240113 -0.146665 14 1
502.513 361.575 0.353556 -0.136077 16 1
149.021 204.492 0.198594 0.256404 1 1
160.736 220.413 0.0992627 0.206257 18 1
410.695 366.188 0.320096 0.0840666 20 1
398.835 61.0347 0.162925 0.081776 20 1
497.014 59.1949 -0.249416 0.239242 15 1
153.751 1.22557 -0.00283959 0.152171 20 1
459.336 177.548 0.297309 0.0990636 11 1
236.685 335.616 0.185583 -0.00510526 19 1
359.599 148.55 0.369466 0.279213 9 1
478.467 421.622 -0.28347 -0.0403472 18 1
426.053 201.598  0.273321 0.150204 5 1
492.597 53.4478 -0.0993111 -0.114191 19 1
335.467 128.234 -0.699557 0.0164072 18 1
```

Comment: *Comment from [Neil](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2921782/neil):* Is there something special about the order of the first file? Reading the question I wonder if the easiest solution might be to sort both files by (X, Y) so that they match.

Comment: @ArtjomB. that was also my first idea... but the files have a different number of points, which can be overcome with a distance-based approach

Comment: @SaulloCastro They don't have different number of points. Well, I was a bit lazy to match them, since it is a bit tedious work.

Comment: @ArtjomB. The order is important because I need to match it with another file based on their orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two arrays DO have the same number of rows you can use `np.lexsort()` which will probably give you a bettter performace, where you could simply do:

```
a = np.loadtxt('file1.txt')
b = np.loadtxt('file2.txt')

aind = np.lexsort((a[:,1], a[:,0]))    
bind = np.lexsort((b[:,1], b[:,0]))

a = a[aind]
b = b[bind]
```

and here the new `a` can be compared with the new `b`...

---

EDIT:
I've removed the distance-based approach after doing some tests with huge files, where it requires enormous amounts of memory... an alternative approach is to use `np.in1d()` in order to identify which values of array `b` are contained in array `a`... which is much more efficient. For a general case where the `x` and `y` columns to be compared are not necessarily the two first columns:

```
import numpy as np

xcol_a = 6
ycol_a = 7
xcol_b = 0
ycol_b = 1
a = np.loadtxt('file1.txt')
b = np.loadtxt('file2.txt')

check_x = np.in1d(a[:, xcol_a], b[:, xcol_b])
check_y = np.in1d(a[:, ycol_a], b[:, ycol_b])
check = (check_x & check_y)
non_existing_indices = np.where(np.logical_not(check))[0]
non_existing_values = a[non_existing_indices]

a = a[check] # taking only the values of a that where also found in b
aind = np.lexsort((a[:, ycol_a], a[:, xcol_a]))
orig_order = np.argsort(aind)
bind = np.lexsort((b[:, ycol_b], b[:, xcol_b]))

a = a[aind][orig_order]
b = b[bind][orig_order]
```

Now the `b` array is sorted according to array `a`, and following the original order of array `a`.

Comment: I want to keep the order of the first file because based on the array index of that I am reading another file and do some calculations.

Comment: If you are sure there is going to be a 1-to-1 matching of the rows of both files, you can sort the second file in the order of the first doing `b = b[bind[np.argsort(aind)]]`